# How can I decrease the mouse sensitivity in zsnes?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, zsnes

I'm using zsnes 1.51 on Ubuntu 16.04. The mouse speed in zsnes is way too high. I'm actually using a touchpad and if I move my finger just a little bit, the cursor moves too much.

Is there any way to decrease the mouse sensitivity? If anybody knows of a good way to move the cursor with the gamepad or arrow keys, I'm fine with that as well.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `zinput.cfg` in the folder with zsnes. Find `Mouse Sensitivity [1..255]` and charge `MouseSensitivity=1` to `2` or `3`.